# If the client does not receive a PINGRESP in the MQTT

Tags: mqtt, keep-alive, mosquitto

If the server receive a PINGREQ the client does not receive a PINGRESP for keep-alive in the MQTT(mosquitto), is the keep-alive time updated?

Answer (score 0):

The keepalive timer is kept on the Broker, it will be reset each time a control packet is received.

So in the situation you described the broker would reset the counter. But since the PINGRESP would be sent via TCP the underlying OS would resend it until it gets a TCP ack, if that doesn't  happen then the connection would be dropped when the TCP timeout is exceeded or the keepalive timeout expires, which ever it first.